# Please explain CEFPython3

Tags: python, webview, kivy, chromium-embedded

I'm a beginner in python/kivy and I want to add a Web view widget to my kivy application. After thorough searching,  I believe using CEFPython should work, but I have no idea on how it works or how to install it on Windows because, the docs aren't so beginner friendly. Lmaoo
Or if there's a better module to achieve Web view but nah smalls shaaw in kivy, I'm open to suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation instructions are in README, just run the `pip install cefpython3` command. See also the Support section.

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/README.md

There are two Kivy examples, but they both were tested only on Linux. You would have to make additional modifications to make it work on Windows:

1. https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/src/linux/binaries_64bit/kivy_.py
2. https://github.com/allestuetsmerweh/garden.cefpython

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate this, Czarek Tomczak. I love your work